# How can i debug my code when i'm targeting multiple versions of .net?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to target multiple .net framework versions with the built in preprocessor directives but i can't debug the targeted version of my code because that part of my code is cannot be hit during debug.

Here's my code:

```
   private static void WriterTask(string processName, byte[] byteArray)
   {
#if NET_46
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            FileWriter(_path, processName, byteArray);
        });
#elif NET_35
        FileWriter(_path, processName, byteArray);
#endif
   }
```

Comment: How are you trying to run this? are your symbols being loaded and are which version of the framework is this being built \ run in?

Comment: I was trying to run it in debug mode and it was built by targeting framework version 4.6.

Comment: you need to change the project to use NET 3.5 temporarliy

Answer (score 1):

If you are debugging an application via Visual Studio, you need to check the framework version you are using to launch it. The corresponding setting can be found in the launch button dropdown.

Here is how this setting looks like in VS2019 for my application, which is targeting both .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET Core 3.0:
[image]
On the screenshot, the .NET Framework 4.5 is selected, but I can switch to .NET Core 3.0 by selecting the corresponding item in the menu.

My application contains a few `#if NET45` sections, and they can be debugged properly in this case.